# ¿Es correcto decir "trama de red"?

Tags: expresiones, significado, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Cuando estoy usando el Wireshark a menudo digo que estoy capturando *tramas*. Sin embargo, esta palabra no tiene [en el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/trama) registrado el uso como "unidad de envío de datos", aunque sí que se recoge por [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trama_de_red). Esta también aclara que el término sería equivalente a *paquete de datos*, que en esta ocasión sí aparece en el DLE:

> **[paquete<sup>1</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/paquete)**
>
> Del fr. *paquet*.
>
> 9. m. *Inform.* Conjunto de programas o de datos.

Visto así, podría decirse que es más correcto decir que con el Wireshark estoy capturando *paquetes de datos* y no *tramas*. Sin embargo, me parece que el uso de *trama* está lo suficientemente extendido, al menos como para estar registrado en la Wikipedia, de hecho la búsqueda ["trama de red"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22trama%20de%20red%22) en Google arroja casi un millón de resultados. En el Wikcionario tampoco se recoge el uso de *[trama](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/trama)* como "paquete de datos".

Pregunta pues: ¿ha aprobado la RAE el uso de "trama de red" para referirse a estas unidades de envío de datos? ¿O se prefiere el uso de "paquete de datos"? De hecho, ¿hay alguna diferencia entre "trama de red" y "paquete de datos"?

Answer (score 7):

*Trama* es una traducción del inglés *[frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(networking))*. Y *[frame](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles/frame)* significa “marco”, es decir, una estructura que rodea a un objeto y le da rigidez o soporte. Es posible que quien haya pensado en la traducción pensara en la trama de una tejido (que es la que hace que un tejido no se deshaga en hilos sueltos) o en la trama de madera de una celosía, o en los alambres que le dan forma a un colchón. Estas tramas están unidas, por supuesto, a un marco, y en cierto sentido forman parte de él y se oponen al objeto en sí (una ventana no es su marco sino el espacio que queda dentro del marco; un colchón es la cosa blanda en la que nos acostamos, no los resortes que lo mantienen con forma).

El *frame*, nuestra *trama*, no es un paquete de datos, sino **la estructura que contiene el paquete**, precedido por un encabezado con bits de sincronización y seguido por un código de chequeo de errores. Es decir, es un contenedor, no el contenido. (El paquete también tiene estructura interna, de manera que tampoco es contenido puro, pero eso ya está en otro nivel de descripción.) Por lo tanto parece que hubiera sido mejor traducir *frame* por *marco* en vez de por *trama*, pero el daño ya está hecho.

Comment: **«el daño ya está hecho»** jajajajajajajaja

Comment: En software libre siempre podemos arreglar la terminología :)

Comment: frame lo podemos traducir como:  elemento, trama, cuadro, estructura, celda, bloque. Que podemos entender como: Estructura de datos formada por campos definidos según un protocolo para la transmisión de datos y funciones de control. Aplicamos este término a la unidad de tamaño fija que transporta bits a lo largo de un enlace material.